# Why the val x = mutable.Map(...) is mutable in scala?

Tags: scala

Considering the following examples

case 1:

```
>scala val x = 1
 x:Int = 1
>scala x = 2
<console>:11: error: reassignment to val
   x=2
    ^
```

case 2:

```
scala> val name = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int]
name: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Int] = Map()

scala>name("Hello") = 1
scala>name
res1: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Int] = Map(Hello -> 1)
```

I can understand the case 1 because x is a `val`-type. For the case 2, although `name` is also `val`-type, `name` is mutable. How to explain it?

Comment: In the first case you are **reassigning** `x`. In the second case you are **mutating** `name`. `name` still refers to the same `Map`. Try writing `name = ...`.

Comment: Are you asking why a mutable map is mutable?

Comment: @JörgWMittag No, I can understand `mutable map` is `mutable`, but I don't know why it can be assigned to a `val-type` variable. The `Answers` tell me the truth that `name` is just a `pointer` to `mutable HashMap` and it can not ***reference/re-assignment*** to another object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mutable.HashMap` is mutable by nature no matter you use `val` or `var`.

But `val` makes a difference if you are mutating/reassigning the reference of instance, as `val` does not allow re-assignment but `var` does.

eg.

**mutating data is allowed,**

```
scala> val mutableMap = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int]
mutableMap: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Int] = Map()

scala> mutableMap += ("some name" -> 8888)
res3: mutableMap.type = Map(some name -> 8888)
```

**but mutating reference is not allowed because of `val`,**

```
scala> mutableMap = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int]
<console>:12: error: reassignment to val
       mutableMap = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int]
                  ^
```

If you want immutable map(no data mutation), use `scala.collection.Map`.

```
scala> val immutableMap = scala.collection.Map("prayagupd" -> 1000)
immutableMap: scala.collection.Map[String,Int] = Map(prayagupd -> 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your second case, name is a `pointer` pointing to `mutable.HashMap` and you are editing the `hashMap` by

```
name("Hello") = 1
```

you have explicitly define `hashmap` as `mutable` thats why you could edit it. But you won't be able to `reference` to another `object` with same `name`  as

```
name = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int]
```

But if you define it with `var` as

```
var name = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int]
```

you can `reference/point` to any other `objects`

Answer (score 1):

> scala> val name = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int]

Here the `reference` is mutable, the `Map` collection is not, you can add/remove elements from that map as its of type `mutable.HashMap`, if you want immutable version try default Scala `Map`.

Qutoting for more details: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html

> Scala collections systematically distinguish between mutable and immutable collections. A mutable collection can be updated or extended in place. This means you can change, add, or remove elements of a collection as a side effect. Immutable collections, by contrast, never change. You have still operations that simulate additions, removals, or updates, but those operations will in each case return a new collection and leave the old collection unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

In your example the val name is an immutable reference to a mutable instance. The hashmap is mutable you explicitly requested one. The name reference is val and not var as such you can not overwrite the reference and will always point to the same object though the object may change.

You could create a var reference to an immutable map to create the opposite affect.